# Getting server name who is executing query in a linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

In SQL Server, I have a server A and I linked a server B to A, so from server A I can execute query like :

```
exec B.DataBase1.dbo.simplePs.
```

My question is how can I get the server who is executing the PS? I tried `@@ServerName` like this :

```
Create procedure simplePs
as
    insert into TRACE(EventInfo) values (@@SERVERNAME)
```

but I get server B not server A.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try querying the `sys.sysprocesses` table - there's lots of useful connection information there e.g.

```
insert into TRACE(EventInfo) 
values (select distinct hostname from sys.sysprocesses where spid = @@SPID)
```

will insert the source hostname of the connection.

Comment: I tested this and it's exactly what I need. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You don't have such context information, for the server B,
the query is executed on its own instance/database.

The best you could do, is to pass the source server as a parameter in the procedure with `@@SERVERNAME` as default value.

```
Create procedure simplePs
@sourceServer as nvarchar(255) = @@SERVERNAME
as
insert into TRACE(EventInfo) values (@sourceServer)
```

Comment: my problem is that sometimes my ps is called but could't find who is calling it .. I think that there is a job somewhere who is calling it .that why I want to trace the server name... I tested this solution but always get server B.

Comment: Your best option is to monitor connexions to the database then. You can do it with SQL Profiler quite easely.